# Measure of product of distribution functions

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $p,q$ be probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ (with Borel-sigma-algebra $B(\mathbb{R})$) together with continuous distribution functions $F_p, F_q$. Let $r$ be the prob. measure with distribution function $F_p \cdot F_q$.

I want to show, that

$r(A) = \int_{A}F_p dq + \int_{A}F_q dp$

is true, for every $A \in B(\mathbb{R})$.

Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to prove that
$
\int_A F_p \, dq = \int_A \, dr - \int_A F_q \, dp,
$
i.e. integration by parts in Lebesgue integral.  This is enough to prove it for $A = (-\infty,a]$.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^a F_p(x) \, dq(x) =\int_{-\infty}^a \int_{-\infty}^x \, dp(y) \, dq(x)
$$
Then apply Fubini's theorem
$$
\int_{-\infty}^a \int_{-\infty}^x \, dp(y) \, dq(x) = \int_{-\infty}^a \int_{y}^a \, dq(x)\, dp(y) = \int_{-\infty}^a (F_q(a) - F_q(y))\, dp(y) \\= F_p(a) F_q(a) - \int_{-\infty}^a F_q(x) \, dp(x)
$$